# Wondering how I can store an address into a temporary block that will be wiped on a loop iteration

Tags: python, random, temporary-files

I am trying to come up with a way to pull 4 files from a directory and to store the address into a temporary file. I am using the random module in Python with the `random.choice(directory)` to pull the pictures. I need to assign these chosen files to temp variables, and on the next iteration wipe the variables so that 4 new files can be picked. I tried using lambda to assign it but it seems a bit too complex. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define the variables before the loop that executes 4 times.
In the beginning of the loop before reading from the files you set the variables equal to NULL